# What is the correct way to determine if user is eligible for free trial with local receipt validation on a Mac App?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, storekit

I am parsing receipts for an auto renewing subscription **locally** on a Mac app.

From [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW1), it would seem that receipt field 1719 should come back as `true` (`1`) when user is in the free trial or introductory pricing.

I've tried this out with the local Xcode configuration (StoreKit testing) and it does come back as true, but this never happens in Sandbox (always `0`).  Should this be working in production?

Does "introductory price period" (field 1719) not imply the free trial?

The same question is being asked in this [Apple forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/66854), but it's from some time ago and doesn't appear that anyone has a clear answer.

Answer (score 3):

To determine if a user is eligible for an introductory offer, you must check the values of the `is_trial_period` (1713) and the `is_in_intro_offer_period` (1719) for all in-app purchase transactions. If either of these fields are true for a given subscription, the user is not eligible for an introductory offer on that subscription product or any other products within the same subscription group.

Personally, I use and recommend [TPInAppReceipt](https://github.com/tikhop/TPInAppReceipt) library, it provides  a variety of convenience methods to validate receipt, determine introductory price eligibility and more. It works well in all possible environment (Sandbox, Production, StoreKitTest).

> Does "introductory price period" (field 1719) not imply the free
> trial?

If you want to check whether a user's subscription is currently in the free trial period you can check `is_in_intro_offer_period` value.

Comment: thanks @tikhop but those fields are what is returned by the JSON, and are not provided in local receipt validation

Comment: @JoeySlomowitz I'm talking about local receipt validation and these fields are available in the local receipt. They were introduced at some point. https://github.com/tikhop/TPInAppReceipt/blob/c47c05f7ed4af821b6836849993082734b541ee5/Sources/InAppPurchase.swift#L56 (line 56 and 58)

Comment: Some discussion about these fields: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/66854. Moreover, I submitter a TSI a while ago and got a confirmation about these fields straight from Apple.

Comment: I noticed that if user change their apple account, they still get free trial while the should have.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found to check for free trial eligibility in LOCAL receipt validation is to simply check for the number of IAP receipts.  If this is empty, the user should be eligible for the free trial, otherwise you can assume that the free trial has already been used.

Comment: Works only if you have one subscription group and don't offer other types of in-app purchase.

Comment: Can you please explain me more about free trial eligibility check?. If passable please share piece of code. Thanks.

Comment: I have since abandoned StoreKit 1 implementation.  If you can abandon support for pre iOS 15 macOS 12, better to use StoreKit 2 - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product/subscriptioninfo/3791958-iseligibleforintrooffer